# Check if column exists prior to renaming it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to rename a column in my events table, as follows:

```
class RenameScheduleToScheduleIdInEventsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    rename_column :events, :schedule, :schedule_id
  end

  def down
    rename_column :events, :schedule_id, :schedule
  end
end
```

This works, but what I would like to do first, to make sure the migration does not fail in the future, is check to see if the column schedule_id is already there, before I try to rename it. How can I do that through a migration?

Comment: check my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use if else condition inside up and down methods.Like below

```
class RenameScheduleToScheduleIdInEventsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    if Event.attribute_names.include? "schedule"
      rename_column :events, :schedule, :schedule_id
    end
  end

  def down
    if Event.attribute_names.include? "schedule_id"
      rename_column :events, :schedule_id, :schedule
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Does ActiveRecord pull this information straight out of the DB or the app? As I've changed the attribute's name in the scaffold, in anticipation of the migration

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper it fetches column name directly from DB.No issues.it works perfectly.Tested code